# Successive scanfs, the second one not asking for the second input from user

Tags: c, scanf

When I run the code it does ask me for my age. But does not ask for the sex? What is the problem with the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int age;
    char sex;

    printf("Enter your age \n");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("Your age is %d \n",age);

    printf("Enter your sex \n");                 
    scanf("%c",&sex);
    printf("Your sex is %c \n",sex);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Previous newline is entered instead.

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf()`: `if (scanf(...) != N) /* error */;` where `N` is the number of expected assignments.

Answer (score 5):

You're leaving a trailing newline from the `age` scanning, which is then considered as a *valid and sufficient* input for following `scanf()` with `%c` format specifier. Change

```
 scanf("%d",&age);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c",&age);
```

to *eat up* the the trailing newline.

---

Having said that, `getch()` is not a standard C function. You should be using [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) instead from `stdio.h`.

Comment: Detail: `scanf("%d%*c",&age);` will "eat up" the following character after `age`, be it a `'\n'` or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Because a trailing newline `\n` is left by the previous `scanf()`..

Try

```
scanf(" %c",&sex);
```

Notice the space before `%c`. The space consumes the left out trailing newline `\n`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int age;
    char sex;

    printf("Enter your age \n");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("Your age is %d \n",age);
    fflush(stdin);     // Library function to clean the buffer..
    printf("Enter your sex \n");                 
    scanf("%c",&sex);
    printf("Your sex is %c \n",sex);
    getch();
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` will clean the buffer `stdin` on some systems, but it is undefined behavior by the C spec and not a portable solution.